# List as value from map cannot be parsed by reduceByKey in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am quite new to coding on Spark using python
My map input is a key-value pair and output is a key-value pair with value as a list of floats.
In the reducer, I want to add the corresponding values in lists for matching keys. Something like this:

```
    map(lambda <some_pair>: (<some_key>,<list_of_floats>)).reduceByKey(lambda list1,list2: [list1[0]+list2[0],list1[1]+list2[1],list1[2]+list2[2]]).collect()
```

However, when I do this, I get the error:

```
    TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I have updated the notations in the map method. The map does take a pair as input from a flatMap. This is just to demonstrate what the input/output to the map and reduceByKey methods are.

Comment: Hi partho, are you sure that <list_of_floats> is really a list?. This error means some of the list1[x] or list2[x] is a float and not a list_of_floats. Only to be sure, you can test it by storing this part: map(lambda <some_pair>: (<some_key>,<list_of_floats>)) in a some variable and then iterate it to see if you really have a list_of_floats in all the positions of your tuple(<Key>,<List_of_Keys>)?

Comment: That's why Scala is the better option for Spark. Type safety means a huge deal when making all these conversions and transformations.